# Create website with facebook login for 0fees.net

Tags: facebook, web-applications

Today I was trying to add Facebook features to my site. It's hosted on `0fees.net`.

On 0fees.net, I uploaded `index.html` to my web host, for example `mysite.0fees.net`. This works, and the page opens fine when I access the URL.

Then, on Facebook, I created my Facebook application, and set the 'Website with Facebook Login' setting as `http://mysite.0fees.net/`, pressed Save Changes. But I got the error message,

> **Error Site URL is not a valid URL.**

When I try set another URL (for example `mysite.1fees.net`) the application saved fine.

I do not want to change provider, so how can I set `mysite.0fees.net`?

Comment: When trying to post the link `http://0fees.net/` on Facebook, you’ll see a message that you can not do so because the domain is __blocked__ for being spammy. So you’ll have to use another domain, I’m afraid. (That’s the problem with cheap webhosting where you’ll only get a subdomain – let one user do something stupid under that main domain, and all other’s using it will get punished as well.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Will have to find another hosting :(

Comment: Today I found a new solution: Attach new domain name to my hosting site. So the name will be bepop.pp.ua(the old is like bepop.0fees.net)... Now api works fine.

Comment: @CBroe. That's an answer. Promote it.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to post the link `http://0fees.net/` on Facebook, you’ll see a message that you can not do so because the domain is blocked for being spammy. So you’ll have to use another domain, I’m afraid. (That’s the problem with cheap webhosting where you’ll only get a subdomain – let one user do something stupid under that main domain, and all other’s using it will get punished as well.)